# "Place code in separate file" in Visual Studio 2008 with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, webforms

I'm reading a book that recommends clicking a check box that says "Place code in separate file" when adding a new Web Form to an existing ASP.NET project.  The book is using Visual Studio 2005 and there is a check box for "Place code in separate file" when you open the "Add New Item" dialog.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I do not see the "Place code in separate file" checkbox when I try to add a new item.  Is there something I need to do to enable this? Was this functionality no longer possible/important in VS 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in 2008 it is the default behaviour.

If you add an apsx file it will add the aspx.cs without any interaction from yourself.

Comment: Ah, I see that now that I open it up in Windows Explorer.  I didn't notice the code behind file in VS's Solution Explorer. Much thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This option depends on the type of project you are building:

- If you are building a Web **Site** (File | New > Web Site, contains an `/App_Code` folder, the code is not compiled into a .dll in the `/bin` folder) then you will have the option (ticked by default in VS2008/2010) to "Place code in separate file", and also "Select master page".
- If you are building a Web **Application** (File | New > Project, doesn't have an `/App_Code` folder, compiles all .cs/.vb files into one .dll in the `/bin` folder) then you don't have the option to not create a separate code file, and when you add a new item it's either a "Web Form" or a "Web Form using Master Page".

Answer (score 1):

VS 2008 adds a code behind file by default.